# How to draw a figure explaining deciles in latex

Tags: diagrams

I am supposed to do a course in which I have to explain what deciles are.
In order to do so I want to do this simple figure

[image]

I am sorry I do not have a MWE but all I know about creating figures in Latex is to link boxes with Tikz, which do not seem very useful here...

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you can link boxes in TikZ I suppose you can draw lines in TikZ. Most of that figure is straight lines ...

Comment: If this is a one time task consider just including the figure as an image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw 
  (0,0) -- ++(10cm,0pt);
\foreach \Valor in {1,...,9}
{
  \draw  (\Valor,-3pt) -- (\Valor,3pt);
}
\draw[->]  
  (5,-3pt) -- 
  ++(0pt,1.2cm) 
    node[above,text=green!80!black] {Mediane: $D5$};
\draw  
  (0,-3pt) -- 
  ++(0pt,15pt) 
    node[above] {$0$\,\euro};
\draw  
  (10,-3pt) -- 
  ++(0pt,15pt) 
    node[above] {$\max$\,\euro};
\foreach \Valor in {0,1,9}
{
  \draw[decorate,orange,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=10pt}]
    (\Valor,-10pt) -- 
    ++(1cm,0pt) 
      node[text=purple,midway,below=12pt] {\SI{10}{\percent}};
}
\draw[decorate,orange,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=30pt}]
  (5,-10pt) -- 
  ++(5cm,0pt) 
    node[text=green!80!black,midway,below=32pt] {\SI{50}{\percent}};
\foreach \Valor/\Texto in {1/1er,9/9e}
{
  \draw[->]
    (\Valor,20pt) -- 
    ++(0pt,25pt) 
      node[text=blue,above] {\Texto\ décile: $D\Valor$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Just a minor question, what it the point of using the \Si command ?

Comment: @Aerandal You're welcome. Using `\Si` from `siunitx` gives you the proper formatting for the units; in this case, for the percentage.